# Forms Authentication - Signing out a user programatically

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, nopcommerce

I'm wondering how to programmatically log a user out, using Forms based authentication.

Online users:

- ADMIN
- User1
- User2
- User3

If I'm the admin, how can I boot User2 out of the system?  FormsAuthentication.Signout() would sign out/delete the cookie from the current user (Admin), which would be quite pointless.

Otherwise, I could put a flag in the database - on the next visit, an action filter would force them to the sign out page and make them log out.  But that seems like a hack.

Comment: You can't do it with built in functionality, so flag in the database is a correct way. Or other way you can place some flag for that user into `HttpContext.Cache` and check it on each visit

Comment: np. done :) moved it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current built in functionality doesn't allow you to signout non current sure, so you can go with your option with flag in the database. Or as another possible way - to store this flag for the user in the some global storage like `HttpContext.Current.Cache` and then check it on each user request. But in that case if you have using `Remember Me` functionality this might not work, as this storage will be flushed with Application restart.

Comment: What I think I'll do, is when the user timeouts, is to store the username in the database in a seperate table.  On any subsequent visit, the user gets redirected to the logout page.  When the user logs in, their name gets remkved from the table.

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine, so user won't get an error during his current request processing, but on the next request he will be logged out.